# What is the meaning of <: in julia?

Tags: julia

Can anyone help me with this code:

```
struct GenericPoint{T<:Real}
x::T
y::T
end
```

What is meaning of `<:` in `{T<:Real}` in Julialang?

Comment: It means "is a subtype of": https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-abstract-types

Answer (score 10):

*Let me begin by saying that the [punctuation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/punctuation/#Punctuation) page of the manual is a handy way to search for such operators, which are otherwise very difficult to look for using a search engine.
In the specific case of `<:`, we find this page, with the relevant documentation for [essential operators](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.:%3C:).*

There are (at least) 3 contexts where `A <: B` might be used, and in all of them this expresses the idea that `A` is a subtype of `B`.

1. as a predicate, `A <: B` returns `true` if and only if all values of type `A` are also of type `B`:

```
julia> Int <: Number
true

julia> Int <: AbstractString
false
```

2. in a type definition, this declares that the newly defined type is a subtype of an existing (abstract) type:

```
# `Foo` is declared to be a subtype of `Number`
struct Foo <: Number
end
```

3. as a type-parameter constraint (like in your example), `T <: Real` expresses the idea that type parameter `T` can be any subtype of `Real`:

```
julia> struct GenericPoint{T<:Real}
           x::T
           y::T
       end

# Works because 1 and 2 are of type Int, and Int <: Real
julia> GenericPoint(1, 2)
GenericPoint{Int64}(1, 2)

# Does not work because "a" and "b" are of type String,
# which is not a subtype of Real
julia> GenericPoint("a", "b")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching GenericPoint(::String, ::String)
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1
```

Note that the use for type-parameter constraints is not restricted to the definition of parametric types, but also applies to function/method definitions:

```
julia> foo(x::Vector{T}) where {T<:Number} = "OK"
foo (generic function with 1 method)

# OK because:
# - [1,2,3] is of type Vector{Int}, and
# - Int <: Number
julia> foo([1, 2, 3])
"OK"

# Incorrect because:
# - ["a", "b", "c"] is of type Vector{String}, but
# - String is not a subtype of Number
julia> foo(["a", "b", "c"])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Array{String,1})
```

Comment: While I still think this is a duplicate, the answer is a very nice summary. You could add that case 3 is really a special case of parametric methods, and that it only constrains the  constructor methods (`GenericPoint{String}` is still a valid thing!).

Comment: @phipsgabler Actually, I get a `TypeError` if I type `GenericPoint{String}` into the REPL on Julia version 1.5. Maybe you're referring to an old behavior that has been fixed?

Comment: Oh, cool. I still have 1.3 and always thought it was just syntactic sugar. Need to read up on this.

Comment: Ah, I'm just stupid. I tested it with `struct Typ{T<:Real} end` and tried `Type{String}` :D

Comment: @phipsgabler Yes, you're right, this is a duplicate. I'm very sorry: I didn't see your comment about this sooner, and when I finished typing this answer I didn't have the courage to discard it. So I was weak and posted it regardless :/

Comment: @phipsgabler you're also right that case 3 applies to methods as well; I should probably add another example illustrating this.